# beamer not showing bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I would like to show the bibliography on a frame of a beamer. But I have not been able to achieve it. This is a short example of the code I have employed.

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%insertar fotos pdf etc... (pdf,png,ps,eps)

\title{Neurohard}
\author{Fabio Galán Prado}
\date[2016]{2016}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hi \cite{158511}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Where the bibliography.bib item is:

@ARTICLE{158511,
author={J. M. Zurada},
journal={IEEE Circuits and Devices Magazine},
title={Analog implementation of neural networks},
year={1992},
volume={8},
number={5},
pages={36-41},
keywords={MOS integrated circuits;analogue computer circuits;multiplying circuits;neural nets;MOS components;adjustable weights;analog control signal;analogue implementation;electrically tunable synapses;integrated-circuit analog multiplier;neural networks;neural processing algorithms;neurocomputers;synaptic connections;Arithmetic;Artificial neural networks;Computer networks;Computer vision;Concurrent computing;Embedded computing;Neural network hardware;Neural networks;Neurons;Very large scale integration},
doi={10.1109/101.158511},
ISSN={8755-3996},
month={Sept},}
```

To compile it, I have followed the instructions given in other forums: pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

I have also try with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%insertar fotos pdf etc... (pdf,png,ps,eps)
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Neurohard}
\author{Fabio Galán Prado}
\date[2016]{2016}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hi \cite{158511}
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{References}
%\bibliography{bibliography}
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: You are missing some style like `\bibliographystyle{plain}` in the first example.

Comment: You second example works out of the box for me.

Comment: Offtopic, you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` as beamer already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using Biblatex, which works with the example bibliography you provided:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Here is a reference: \citet{158511}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting bibliography looks like this:

[image]

From here you can set about changing the style to your needs. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Here is a reference: \citet{158511}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the `bibtex` example, the style is missing, e.g. something like `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Neurohard}
\author{Fabio Galán Prado}
\date[2016]{2016}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hi \cite{158511}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You second example compiles fine for me. But remember that you have to clean your auxiliary files, if you make the switch from `bibtex` to `biblatex`.

[image]